# If φ is onto and R' is a field, prove that Ker φ is a maximal ideal of R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

This is my proof.

Let Φ: R->R' be a ring homomorphismm. Then R/KerΦ is isomorphic to Φ(R). Since Φ(R) is onto and R' is a field, then R/KerΦ is also a field. Let R be a commutative ring with unity. Since R/KerΦ is a field, then kerΦ is a maximal ideal of R.

Any comment on my proof? Thank you.

in this question, its not stated that R is a commutative ring while the ones posted here has R as a commutative ring.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459728/proving-maximal-ideals).

Comment: Are they exactly the same? In this question, its not stated that R is a commutative ring while the ones you posted has R as a commutative ring.

Comment: Note that if $\Phi$ is an homomorphism from (unital ring) $R$ to a commutative ring then $\ker \Phi$ contains the two sided ideal $[R,R]=\sum_{a,b\in R} R(ab-ba)R$  and $R/[R,R]$ is a commutative ring. In general if $[R,R]=R$ then there is no homomoprhism from $R$ to a commutative ring (other than the $0$ one), this is the case when $R=M_2(\Bbb{C})$, which has no maximal two-sided ideal.

Comment: So based on my proof. Its right to say that R is a commutative ring with unity?